# AmazonSQSClient.setRegion() necessary?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I'm wondering if it's necessary to set region?
it seems to be redundant since we already give the queue URL which also includes the region.
Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/AmazonWebServiceClient.html#setEndpoint(java.lang.String)) for `setRegion` state that it's an alternative to setting an endpoint (URL):

> An alternative to setEndpoint(String), sets the regional endpoint for this client's service calls.

You basically use one or the other to set up the client.

See how in [this sample from AWS](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/src/samples/AmazonSimpleQueueService/SimpleQueueServiceSample.java) it's used without setting the endpoint.

And in the [source](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/AmazonWebServiceClient.java#L356) of the AmazonWebServiceClient (from which AmazonSQSClient inherits), you can see how `setRegion` builds the endpoint.

Comment: so, if I'm using SendMessageBatchRequestEntry(queueUrl), ReceiveMessageRequest(queueUrl), DeleteMessageBatchRequest(queueUrl) and GetQueueAttributesRequest(queueUrl), no need to use setRegion()? just want to make sure that there are no unforeseen negative side effect

Comment: Do you provide a full queue URL, including endpoint? In this case, setting region is not necessary.

Comment: and btw, the https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/src/samples/AmazonSimpleQueueService/SimpleQueueServiceSample.java does set the region.

Comment: Yes, the sample sets the region because it passes only the last part of url to the request. See how the full url is later obtained in the sample.